# sum of maximum bill amount total for the date

Tags: mysql

```
branch_id      bill_amount_total     billdate
6               1000                 05-06-12
6               1000                 06-06-12
7               2000                  05-06-12
7               500                  06-06-12
8               700                    05-06-12
8               800                    06-06-12
6               200                    05-06-12  
7              200                    05-06-12  
8              200                    05-06-12 



SELECT branch_id, sum(bill_amount_total) as max_amount,bill_date
    FROM pos_master 
    group by bill_date order by max_amount desc
```

I need the maximum of sum of bill amount total for the particular date

Comment: First of all, strore dates using a date data type. Secondly, once the data set has been corrected, what would the desired result set look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
SELECT branch_id,bill_date,max(max_amount,bill_date) FROM (
 SELECT 
   branch_id,
   bill_date,
   sum(bill_amount_total) as max_amount,bill_date
 FROM pos_master group by bill_date order by max_amount desc ) as x
GROUP BY bill_date having bill_date between '2012-06-05' and '2012-06-07' ;
```

Comment: This returns an arbitrary branch id

Comment: No its not working ..group by branch_id is not taken.

Comment: SELECT branch_id,bill_date,max(max_amount) FROM (
 SELECT 
   branch_id,
   bill_date,
   sum(bill_amount_total) as max_amount
 FROM pos_master group by bill_date order by max_amount desc ) as x

Comment: Its giving only one branch_id amount ..I need all branch_id sum of bill_amount_total group by bill_date

Answer (score -1):

U CAN TRY BELOW METHOD

i added sample date and table

```
SELECT SUM(Total) FROM Orders

WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN ‘3/1'2014' AND ‘3/31/2014'
```

Comment: SELECT 2 BETWEEN 3 AND 1;